# NDSolve Problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, chemistry

I am trying to solve a chemical equilibrium ODE with NDSolve where one function is the argument to another.

I.E. My equations look like:

```
A'[t] == B[t] + f[A[t]] C[t],
B'[t] == ...,
C'[t] == ...
```

This is the actual code:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
  T'[t] == -((uCO[T[t]] nCO'[t] + uO[T[t]] nO'[t] + uO2[T[t]] nO2'[t] + uCO2[T[t]] nCO2'[t])/(CvCO[T[t]] nCO[t] + CvO[T[t]] nO[t] + CvO2[T[t]] nO2[t] + CvCO2[T[t]] nCO2[t])),
  nCO'[t] == -nCO[t] nO[t] m[t] r1[T[t]] - nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] + nCO2[t] m[t] r1b[T[t]] + nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]],
  nO'[t] == -nCO[t] nO[t] m[t] r1[T[t]] + nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] - 2 nO[t] nO[t] m[t] r3[T[t]] + nCO2[t] m[t] r1b[T[t]] - nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]] + 2 nO2[t] m[t] r3b[T[t]],
  nO2'[t] == -nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] + nO[t] nO[t] m[t] r3[T[t]] + nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]] - nO2[t] m[t] r3b[T[t]],
  nCO2'[t] == nCO[t] nO[t] m[t] r1[T[t]] + nCO[t] nO2[t] r2[T[t]] - nCO2[t] m[t] r1b[T[t]] - nCO2[t] nO[t] r2b[T[t]],
  m'[t] == nCO'[t] + nO'[t] + nO2'[t] + nCO2'[t],
  T[0] == 1500,
  nCO[0] == nCOinit,
  nO[0] == 0.,
  nO2[0] == nO2init,
  nCO2[0] == 0.,
  m[0] == nCOinit + nO2init
  },
 {T, nCO, nO, nO2, nCO2, m},
 {t, 0.00, 1.00},
 MaxSteps -> 300000
 ]
```

The problem is that my functions:

```
CvCO2, CvCO, CvO, CvO2, uCO2, uCO, uO2, uO, r1, r2, r3, r1b, r2b, r3b
```

can only take a numeric value argument.

Mma spits our many errors due to that...

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

This is a very frequently asked question, but I agree it might not be so easy to find out what is happening.  The solution is defining the functions as

```
f[x_ ? NumericQ] := ...
```

to prevent them from evaluating for non-numerical arguments

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs, but I have declared my functions like that yes and it doesn't help. In fact, I haven't notice any changes.

Comment: @JonathanRoy You need to clear them first, otherwise both definitions persist (check it using `?f`).  So evaluate `Clear[f]`.  But since you have so many, just start with a fresh kernel (Evaluation -> Quit Kernel) to test this.

Comment: For some reason, I had to close Mma and re-open my notebook and now it works! Is there any way to 'reset' the notebook without having to restart Mma?

Comment: Haha you answered my question while I was commenting. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Jonathan Whenever I have a function that has a not-totally-general pattern, such as `f[x_?NumericQ]`, I precede the definition with `Clear[f]`.  This way I make sure that when I change the definition (and possibly change the patter as well), I won't end up with several coexisting definitions that I don't want.  It's useful to make this a habit.